# powershell, loop id value in a api url to get data in one json

Tags: powershell, api, rest, loops, powershell-3.0

Thanks for the quick response, modified my code.  Have one doubt, should the last line included in the curly brackets or outside.

$filepath="C:\Users\bvt\Desktop\FILE.txt"

$names=Get-Content -Path $filepath

foreach($name in $names){
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"

$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 8674747647647h--9656564766")

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod https://ccd/mpe.com/api/v3/projects/108184/test-runs/$name/test-logs  -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers

$response1 | ConvertTo-json -Depth 8

}
$data| ConvertTo-json -Depth 8 | Out-File

Comment: You can just use an ArrayList here to store the entire thing. `Systems.Collection.Arraylist` is  the Object that you would refer an create. 

For looping, I am not seeing any loop statement here. Use `Foreach` loop to do the same and store the result each time in the array list .

Comment: What would be the difference between `$link` and `$link2` ? Are you reading complete urls from these files or just ID values? What do you mean with _"till it converts to JSON finally as a file"_ ? Why store the respons from `Invoke-RestMethod` in a variable and next convert whatever you read from the file in `$link` to JSON?

Comment: Modified the code in the question above, please suggest any corrections. thanks